# How to place code snippets within Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I've really enjoyed [Anders Hejlsberg presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-816T) at BUILD 2011 and it's not the first time that I notice someone having a collection of code snippets available within Visual Studio's *Toolbox* window, so given that all the searches I've performed so far pointed me to how to deal with IntelliSense snippets, I was wondering if anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Just select the text and drag it to the toolbox.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to copy the code to the toolbox. A simple selection of the code, and a drag and drop to the toolbox just make it available. It will not be deleted until you delete it (at least that never happens to me by itself)..

This is what you need?

Comment: Wow that was easy and definitely what I'm looking for -- thanks much for the contribution gbianchi!